# Ionic shareViaFacebook Firebase Storage Image

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

Hi I am trying to use the Ionic Native Social Sharing function:

shareViaFacebook(message, image, url)

I have some images stored in firebase storage.

I am passing the image.downloadURL from firebase into the image argument and the url argument and neither of them are working.

The url I am passing is the 

`// "Public" unguessable URL, accessible by anyone with the link
// This is secured because that token is *very* hard for someone to guess
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/bucket/object?alt=media&token=<token>`

I tried using encodeURL and encodeURLComponent but cannot get the ionic app to share the firebase stored image to facebook.

I am able to share other photos, such as any random google image photo by passing the url of the image to the image argument.

Answer (score 4):

> Convert the image into base64 string and then send it to `shareViaFacebook()`

**Working code snippet**

```
function shareImage(image) {
    getImage(image)
        .then(function(base64) {

            // check for the required dependencies to avoid runtime JS errors
            $window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(
                'Add a message here..', // this message would auto-populate as caption
                base64, // image to be shared in base64 format
                null,
                function(result) {
                    // This is successCallback()
                },
                function(error) {
                    // This is errorCallback()
                }
            );
        });
}

function getImage(image) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    getBase64(URI,
        function(image) {
            deferred.resolve(image);
        }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
}

// There are many ways to get base64 from URI. 
// I followed Approach 2 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/2458543
function getBase64(src, callback, outputFormat) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;

        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);

        callback(dataURL);
    };

    img.src = src;

    // observation - if below code is removed, then image does not load correctly
    if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
        img.src = src;
    }
}
```

---

**Some of my important observations while implementing `shareViafacebook()`**

> successCallback() and errorCallback() for Android and iOS platforms are quite different

**`Android`**

1. *If fb app is NOT installed* - errorCallback(error) is invoked where [error = Array(all_apps)]
2. *If fb app is installed*

   - User not logged in - successCallback(result) is invoked where [result = "OK"]
   - User logged in - successCallback(result) is invoked where [result = "OK"]

*This does not wait for successfully sharing the image and returns as soon as the facebook app opens*

3. *Cancelled (by user)* - Do Nothing

---

**`iOS`**

1. *If fb app is NOT installed* - errorCallback(error) is invoked where [error = "cancelled"]
2. *If fb app is installed*

   - User not logged in - errorCallback(error) is invoked where [error = "cancelled"]
   - User logged in - successCallback(result) is invoked where [result = true]

*This waits for successfully sharing the image and returns on completing the share action*

3. *Cancelled (by user)* - errorCallback(error) is invoked where [error = "cancelled"]